# External Apache tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Why do we use external tomcat server while working in the industry though there is support for the server in the Eclipse?

Previously I was using the server integrated with the eclipse itself. But now as a part of the industry I've started using the external tomcat server.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE -- a development tool. The external Tomcat server is production-ready, and has no dependency on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The reason we use external server during development is that the server integrated with Eclipse works most of the time but not all of the time. This you will notice when there are multiple number of web application being deployed as part of the development in your Eclipse and you start and stop Tomcat a number of times to refresh web applications in rapid succession. The problems that can happen are:

1) Source/WAR files updated but deployed application does not update
2) Tomcat throws exception during start within Eclipse
3) A web context becomes unavailable from within eclipse

all the above are not limitations of either eclipse or tomcat, since we change the deployables in rapid succession, sometimes the WAR files get corrupted while exporting or old remnants of previously deployed files remain within tomcat work/localhost directory.

In general this kind of errors become difficult to determine. the best way to avoid them is to have a separate tomcat and export the WAR to the webapp directory, even then it is good to clear the work/localhost directory from time to time.